# Display comments of users on single page

Tags: plugins, posts, comments, plugin-recommendation

I don't know if i can explain this..

I want to create a Page where the comments of specific user is listed. like this format...

### User Name

```
       Post Tilte
       - comment
       - comment
       - comment


       Post Tilte
       - comment
       - comment
       - comment
```

well, im not looking exactly as that format, but I want something similar to that. I already have a page where all the posts by specific user is listed, now this time I want list of comments. Is that possible? Or is there any available plugin that can provide me that function? Any answers or recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can use the [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function to retrieve comments from a specific user.

```
$comments = get_comments( array( 'user_id' => 1 ) );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    setup_postdata( $post );
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
    echo $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chris, that should do my problem, but Is there a way to add the Title of the post? with link to the post's permalink. Sorry if im asking too much.

Comment: ok, sorry I think I just need to refer to the codex :) thank you.

Comment: See edit.  get_comments returns the post id for the original post the comment was made to.  Using get_post and setup_postdata.  You can access the template tags referencing the original post.